# Find address recursively from latitudes and longitudes in google map api

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3

I have some latitudes and  longitudes i want to find out their addresses.

```
function OnSuccess(response) {
    showLatLng(0, JSON.parse(response.d).Table, JSON.parse(response.d).Table.length);
}
```

Where `JSON.parse(response.d).Table` contains the result set.

```
function showLatLng(index, resultSet, totalLen) {
    var lat = resultSet[index].x;
    var lng = resultSet[index].y;

    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

    new google.maps.Geocoder().geocode({ 'latLng': latlng },
        function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                if (results[0]) {

                    var z = " <tr>" +
                        "<td>" + results[0].formatted_address + "</td>" +
                        "</tr>";

                    $("#result").append(z);

                    if (index < totalLen) {
                        showLatLng(index + 1, resultSet, totalLen);
                    }
                }
            }
        });
}
```

This code is working only 4 to 5 times then stops and no error in firebug.
Please give me a better way to do this.

EDIT:
Lucas You are absolutely right.

Previously I have used loop with timeout as below

```
 $.each(JSON.parse(response.d).Table, function (index, value) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            showLatLng(index , value.x, value.y);
        }, (index + 1) * 7000);
    });
```

But for some reason (because I think it is working on async call)  it is skipping some results.

Comment: it could be that your loop is operating too fast for the geocoder, which has a throttle tht prevents pretty much exactly what you are trying to do. Although 4 or 5 times wouldn't seem to be enough to trigger that. You could try setTimeout on your recursion, or add an else to your `if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {` and console.log the `google.maps.GeocoderStatus` there. But really, if you have a known list of coordinates the best thing to do is geocode them once and hardcode the addresses in an array or whatever rather than calling the geocoder every time the page loads

Answer (score 0):

pass Latitude and Longitude value to script

```
function GetAddress() {
        var lat = parseFloat(document.getElementById("txtLatitude").value);
        var lng = parseFloat(document.getElementById("txtLongitude").value);
        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
        var geocoder = geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode({ 'latLng': latlng }, function (results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                if (results[1]) {
                    alert("Location: " + results[1].formatted_address);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: How can you do it for 20 records (recursively)  in an object containing latitude and longitude ?

Comment: can you send me the whole program you have